# jQuery trigger onChange

Tags: function, onchange

I have a `input` text field which is filled with the url of an image using a jQuery function.
How do I use the "onChange" event of the `input` to run the jQuery function?

Comment: Are you using a hash(#) in the url?

Comment: So what does the url look like? I think I can write something for you, but I'm confused as to what you want exactly. Do you want to move this to chat?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where is your code?  How about a working demo?  Read this and try editing your question accordingly:  https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: please write your code,so that we can help.

Answer (score 18):

If you update field by JavaScript, than after changing value just call on it `change()`

```
$('#myId').val('new_url').change();
```

Comment: also tryed this but dont update if the field is updated by other script

Answer (score 13):

Try this -

```
$('#myId').trigger('change');
```

Put it in any function where you are changing the url in the textbox.

Comment: And also make sure you trigger the event after declaring it inside JS ;)

Answer (score 6):

try this :

```
$("#myId").trigger('event_name')
```

where event_name is the event you've bound your checker function, such as keyUp or change

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine the problem lies with `.change()` perhaps somewhere else in your code, I have just tested and the event will get fired if I copy and paste, or if I type some new text (with both normal and onscreen keyboard).

The only time it didn't seem to trigger was when I dragged some text clipping from the desktop to the input box but this was to do with it being highlighted and sure enough when the input box lost focus the event triggered (I can't think of any other use cases)

You can do something like below using the `blur()` or `focusout()` event which essentially I believe is the [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onchange) event

```
function foo(e) {
    alert(e.type + ' triggered');
}

$('input').blur(function(e) {
    $t = $(this);
    if ($t.data('oVal') != $t.val()) {
        $t.data('oVal', $t.val());
        foo(e);
    }
})
```